# Overflow when trying to bind double.max_value in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to get our Hibernate app running on Oracle 11g, but we keep getting the following error when trying to persist a double.max_value:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Overflow Exception trying to bind 1.7976931348623157E308
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DoubleBinder.bind(OraclePreparedStatement.java:15676)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2948)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2202)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3468)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2437)
... 11 more
```

**Does anyone know why we can't persist this value?**

We only have this problem in Oracle -- Postgres and H2 work fine.

We've tried forcing the Oracle datatype to Number and Binary_Double, but with the same result. We are using Hibernate 3 and Oracle 11g, along with the oracle jdbc driver and the OracleSpatial10g dialect.

(I'm a Hibernate and Oracle newbie, so any help is appreciated.)

EDIT: Some helpful comments so far, but I still haven't figured out my issue. Here's some more info:

- I found out that I can insert the number straight into the DB using BINARY_DOUBLE. I tried it with sqlfiddle and through my local db using SQLDeveloper. I can also retrieve it in SQLDeveloper.
- My problem is that I can't ever commit the number to my Database... The exception is thrown *before* anything makes it into the db.

Comment: convert scientific notation to decimal notation and then persist !

Comment: What do you mean? How could I represent double.max_value without scientific notation?

Comment: I think that this value is bigger than the max oracle DB NUMBER datatype, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @Tomas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145950/1083652), there is a datatype `binary_double` which its max value is the value you need.

Here is how you can insert `1.7976931348623157E308` to a table as a numeric value

```
create table t1 (big_val binary_double);
insert into t1 values( cast('1.7976931348623157E308' as binary_double) );
```

Comment: This eliminates the database as the cause of the problem, but I still don't know what's going on. My guess is something strange in the OJDBC driver, since that's where the error originates. Weird.

Comment: Not really, if your table has a `number` datatype then the origin of the exception is in the DB- `ORA-01426: numeric overflow`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i140176) your value is too big, even for the `BINARY_DOUBLE`

Comment: I agree, but this number is exactly Java's double.max_value. Does this mean that we can _never_ persist a double.max_value in Oracle?

Comment: It just seems like this would be a really common issue for Hibernate users. I haven't found any mentions of it on SO or elsewhere.

Comment: @burnsy, I'm not sure about how hibernate works, but you can store this value to oracle db, see this fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0aa1/1

Comment: @A.B.Cade Good find... I also just confirmed that I can insert it into my local db. Have to say, this is not what I expected. Maybe this is a bug in the OJDBC driver?

Comment: @burnsy, then I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

@A.B.Cade is correct that the value can be inserted by casting the value from a character string to BINARY_DOUBLE, either by performing the cast explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(TEST_VAL)
  VALUES (CAST ('1.7976931348623157E308' AS BINARY_DOUBLE))
```

or implicitly:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(TEST_VAL)
  VALUES ('1.7976931348623157E308')
```

(assuming that TEST_TABLE has a column TEST_VAL declared as BINARY_DOUBLE).

However, if you try to retrieve these values using a client-server tool (I tested using PL/SQL Developer from Allround Automations - v.8.0.4.1514 FWIW) to execute a SELECT such as

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
```

you get the following error:

```
ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation
```

which requires a cast to VARCHAR2 to work around.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can save this as string on Oracle. I've tested it and it works.
On java:

```
Double d = Double.MAX_VALUE;
PreparedStatement pstmt;
// ...
// INSERT INTO x VALUES(?)

pstmt.setString(1, d.toString());


// SELECT BIG_DOUBLE_COL from x

    String str = rs.getString(1);
    Double nd = str==null?null:new Double(str);
```

On the database:
create table x (BIG_DOUBLE_COL BINARY_DOUBLE);

Just beware that other databases don't seem to accept Double.MAX_VALUE's string representation as a valid Double (i.e. they can't parse it), so this doesn't work for all databases. But those databases normally accept using the setDouble method with Double.MAX_VALUE. This is for example the case with Ingres.